# Pub failed to rename directory because access was denied

Tags: flutter

Whenever I run `flutter doctor` or `flutter pub get`, I am getting the following error

---

```
Pub failed to rename directory because access was denied.     
This may be caused by a virus scanner or having a file in the directory open in another application.    
Running "flutter pub get" in flutter_tools...    
pub get failed (1; in the directory open in another application.)
```

---

I have tried some commands, ran the commands in administrator mode, but still getting the same error.

Comment: run your terminal as administrator and try again these commands

Comment: already tried, didn't work

Answer (score 1):

For me it helped to delete the 'pubspec.lock' file in the project folder and the run `flutter pub get` again

Comment: thank you, but did not work for me

Answer (score 1):

The source of my problem was that I had flutter installed directly in the C directory. After moving it to another directory (worked for me under MyUser/Downloads) the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced a similar problem.

so, running `flutter clean` in terminal solved the problem.

Comment: thanks, but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I have deactivated my Anti-Virus and it worked for me! - Deactivate Antivirus